# validate 2 dropdowns (only some combinations valid)

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I am completely new to JavaScript.
I have size and color dropdowns on a page for users to order a product, but only certain combinations are available i.e. pink is the only color in large sizes.
I thought I'd make an array of allowed sizes and test the user input against these.
If the choice is invalid then I want a popup to tell the user why.

In the real world I'll use SQL & PHP to create the array of allowed choices, in the example below I've hard coded 3 valid choices for testing. Unfortunately the code below doesn't do anything.
I'm sure it's a simple newb mistake. I really don't know what I'm doing :)
Can somebody help me out?

The validation function is supposed to happen when user clicks the form submit...

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_form()"
      action="cart.php">
```

Here's the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function validate_form() {
    var allowed = new Array();
        allowed[0]="10,beige";      
        allowed[1]="10,black";
        allowed[2]="10,pink";

    var chosenColInd = document.getElementById("colID");
    var chosenColText = colID.options[colID.selectedIndex].text;
    var chosenSizeInd = document.getElementById("sizeID");
    var chosenSizeText = sizeID.options[sizeID.selectedIndex].text;
    var chosenSizeCol = chosenSizeText+","+chosenColText; 
    var found = "false";

    for ( var i = 0; i < allowed.length; i++ ) {
        if (allowed[i]=chosenSizeCol) {
            found = "true";
        }
    }
    if (found = "false") {
        alert( 'The variation you have selected is currently unavailable. Please select another.' );
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few lines where you use the assignment operator (that is single equals `=`) instead of one of the equality operators (that is double or triple equals, triple is usually preferred in JavaScript). Example:

```
if (found = "false") {
```

Would appear to be the problem at first sight - it's an assignment not a comparison :) use triple equals `===` instead of single:

```
if(found === "false") {
```

Also, consider the following (commented) updates to your code, which reflects more the typical style of JavaScript code:

```
function validate_form() {

    //no need to use new Array(), use array literal instead
    var allowed = [
        "10,beige",      
        "10,black",
        "10,pink"
    ];

    var chosenColInd = document.getElementById("colID");
    var chosenColText = colID.options[colID.selectedIndex].text;
    var chosenSizeInd = document.getElementById("sizeID");
    var chosenSizeText = sizeID.options[sizeID.selectedIndex].text;
    var chosenSizeCol = chosenColText+","+chosenSizeText; 
    var found = "false";


    for ( var i = 0; i < allowed.length; i++ ) {

        //use equality operator instead of assignment
        if (allowed[i]===chosenSizeCol) {
            found = true; //may as well use a boolean rather than string
            break; //exit loop early, no need to continue if we've already found 
        }
    }
    if (!found) { //no need to do a comparison with already boolean values
        alert( 'The variation you have selected is currently unavailable. Please select another.' );
    }
    //may as well just return found here now that we're using a boolean
    return found;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ever so much for your help. Your comments are excellent and make perfect sense. Unfortunately I can't get your code to work either.  Here's a link to the test page if that helps: http://archers.net.au/onlineStore/test.php

Comment: i see you're using the variable `colID` before it is declared anywhere in the above script, i assumed this was intentional but this is likely the cause if you're still having problems. Are you familiar with web development tools like firebug? If you need further assistance please create a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the HTML and script included so i do not make further assumptions

Comment: Thanks again. ColID is simply the dropdown id (<select name="ColID" id="ColID">) as far as I can tell from w3schools that's all I need. I got chosenColText+","+chosenSizeText; the wrong way around but have fixed it. I suspect the function isn't even being called. I can provide the html (I have), I'm not understanding jsfiddle & am on a deadline. I'm sure this is something utterly simple. Thanks again Steve

Comment: You were right both times (many thanks). Your edits made perfect sense and the only reason they didn't work was that I didn't properly reference document.getElementById(id)

For anyone who might follow the (id) needs both form name and the dropdown ID, like so:
 var chosenIndex = document.formName.dropDownID.selectedIndex; //provides selected dropdown index

followed by:
var chosenText = document.formName.dropDownID.options[chosenIndex].text; //selected dropdown text

(I left out the formName and nothing happened, javascript doesn't seem to generate errors).

Thanks again.

Comment: no problems, glad to be of help, sounds like you learnt from it as well - which is always a bonus. Please consider marking as answer. Oh and as an aside, i would completely avoid W3School as a source of information, the mozilla docs are much better https://developer.mozilla.org